# Multiple View Controllers and one view nib

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I want to achieve the following:

I have a nib which has a View Controller which is responsible for that view.

I want to write classes which inherit from this view controller and therefore share the same nib file as the base view controller but add additional specific code. I could just build a whole lot of functionality into the base view controller but then it gets messy; I really want to be able to have the same base structure with one nib and then have subclasses which add additional features.

The trouble I am having is in instantiating (in code) the subclasses using the base class's view.

I have tried [NSBundle nibWithNibName:...] and [[vc alloc] initWithNib:...] - they all give errors.

Do I set the file's owner to the base class? Do I set the view's custom view controller for the base class? How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What errors do you get from `[[vc alloc] initWithNibName:...]`?

Comment: [UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "APDayView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'. In my base class's nib I have set the Custom View Controller Class to my base class's type. I have left File's Owner blank - this is what I normally to do to associate classes with nibs.

Comment: If I set the file's owner I get the error message saying I have associated my view with two view controllers (the custom class view controller and the file's owner) and then if I subsequently leave the 'custom class vc' box blank and set the file's owner only, I get error messages saying '[UIViewController.. is not key-coding compliant for [outlets]' ie. it thinks the class is a generic view controller and doesnt instantiate the file's owner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set up outlets from the view controller to the view or subviews, you must set the File's Owner in the nib to the view controller's class.

The *actual* view controller can be a subclass of the class declared as the File's Owner in the nib. But then the *outlets* must still be in the superclass, or you won't be able to load using the *other* subclass.

So for example let me call the view controller SuperVC, Sub1VC, and Sub2VC. Then:

- Define *all* needed outlets in SuperVC
- Declare File's Owner in the nib as a SuperVC
- Draw all outlet connections in the nib, including `view` of course

Now say:

```
Sub1VC* vc = [[Sub1VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibname" bundle:nil];
```

Or:

```
Sub2VC* vc = [[Sub2VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibname" bundle:nil];
```

They will both work.

Comment: And if you want to understand _why_ that works, see my discussion of the nib-loading mechanism starting here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner

Comment: Is there any way to do this if the class is not a view controller? I was hoping to do this for views that are directly in nibs with no view controllers in sight (though I think I'll have to change this).

Thank you matt!

Comment: @Yar certainly. This has nothing to do with view controllers. Did you even look at the discussion in my book that I linked to in my comment?

Comment: Yes, and I am still looking. However, I can't yet understand how changing the File Owner to *be* the NSView subclass allows me to change the class of the NSView subclass instance that I'm using in the nib. I'll keep looking at your chapter and trying things, of course

Comment: "However, I can't yet understand how changing the File Owner to be the NSView subclass" The File's owner should not be the NSView subclass. It should be the class of the object that will be the _owner_ when you load the nib. Or you can load the nib with _no_ owner and just grab the topmost object (the view).

Comment: As the book goes on, I actually do it all for you right there: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_making_and_loading_a_nib and the next section.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's perfect. Unfortunately, what I'm working with -- and working around it, but wouldn't mind figuring it out -- is that I'm using `-[NSViewTable registerNib:forIdentifier:]` and then pulling them back out with `makeViewWithIdentifier`...  I think that in my particular case, you cannot dynamically choose the class of any of the objects, not even the owner...?

Comment: @Yar but that sounds like a separate question! You should click Ask Question and ask it. I can't help because I don't know what an NSViewTable is, but I'm sure someone can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I see it all now: the second method for `NSTableView` allows a specification of owner, `makeViewWithIdentifier(_:owner:)`... However, there's still no way to change the class of one of the objects in the NIB's graph, so I'd need to restructure a bit. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to set the view outlet.

This is a seriously common mistake. Just `control + drag` from the File's Owner (the base view controller), to the top level view, and set the outlet of `view`.

Comment: If I set the file's owner I get the error message saying I have associated my view with two view controllers (the custom class view controller and the file's owner) and then if I subsequently leave the 'custom class vc' box blank and set the file's owner only, I get error messages saying '[UIViewController.. is not key-coding compliant for [outlets]' ie. it thinks the class is a generic view controller and doesnt instantiate the file's owner class